Как сохранить переменные в телеграм боте на Python после перезагрузки
Я новичок в создании ботов на Python. У меня есть переменная баланса, но после перезапуска бота она всегда сбрасывается. Как сделать так чтобы она всегда сохранялась.

str или arr
попробуй эти два оператора
